# Spring boot dependencies error gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, dependencies

I have a new spring boot project and I have included some dependencies. The thing is that on the first run the 'rest' and 'jpa' dependencies are working just fine, but on the second run I'm getting a huge error.

```
dependencies {
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-remote-shell')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-facebook')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-twitter')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

The error message it the following(it was too big to paste it here):
[error msg](http://paste.ofcode.org/kd3HrQEihgNDaQ4HcHnAkd)

I'm using Intelij IDEA 2016.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important error message from this stack trace seems to be:

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active)
```

It says that you didn't define what database to use (what kind of an where it is located).
I guess you need to add some properties to your `application.properties` file, like:

```
spring.datasource.url = (URL to your data source)
spring.datasource.driverClassName = (fully qualified class name of your datasource driver)
```

You could use an H2 in memory database using this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:databaseName;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Note that you also need to include the dependencies for the database into your Gradle dependencies (`compile('com.h2database:h2')` for an H2).

Answer (score 0):

With java-errors like this you see that there are a lot of lines starting with `Caused by:`, this is because in the code there are many places where the code catched an exception and then threw it again.
To find the real issue you need to take a look at the last `Caused by`-entry:

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I cannot say what the issue itself is with the information you gave. But there are [some other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+determine+embedded+database+driver+class+for+database+type+NONE) at stackoverflow that handle this message.